# State value `undefined` on state onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Writing a component named `Member` where I'm doing some calculations which I store in `this.state` before sending it somewhere else, but I got a problem, when firing one of `onChange` handlers some values of state are `undefined` , but should be filled some value.

Component `Member`

```
import React from "react";

import {calcSCR, difference, multiply} from "../../utils/Calculations";
import {SCR_COEFF} from "../../constants/calc";

class Member extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: "1",
            full_name: 'Mocked member 1',
            role: 'Developer',
            salary: 1650,
            hourly_cost: 19.6, // SCR = (gross * coeff) / 100
            project_data: {
                project_id: '1',
                hourly_rate: 40,
                occupation: 50,
                estimate_hours: 70,
                revenue: 2800,// revenue = estimate_hours * hourly_rate
                cost: 1372,// cost = estimate_hours * hourly_cost
                profit: 1428// profit = revenue - cost
            }
        };

        this.onSalaryChange = this.onSalaryChange.bind(this);
        this.onHourlyCostChange = this.onHourlyCostChange.bind(this);
        this.onHourlyRateChange = this.onHourlyRateChange.bind(this);
        this.onEstimateHoursChange = this.onEstimateHoursChange.bind(this);
        this.onRevenueChange = this.onRevenueChange.bind(this);
        this.onCostChange = this.onCostChange.bind(this);
        this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this);
        this.onOccupationChange = this.onOccupationChange.bind(this);

        this.save = this.save.bind(this);

    }

    save(){

    }

    onNameChange(e){
        this.setState({
            full_name: e.target.value
        })
    }

    onSalaryChange(e){
        let salary = e.target.value;

        this.setState({
            salary: salary,
            hourly_cost: calcSCR(salary, SCR_COEFF)
        })
    }

    onHourlyRateChange(e){
        let hourly_rate = e.target.value;
        let estimate_hours = this.state.project_data.estimate_hours;

        this.setState({
            project_data: {
                hourly_rate: hourly_rate,
                revenue: multiply(estimate_hours, hourly_rate)
            }
        })

    }

    onOccupationChange(e){
        this.setState({
            project_data: {
                occupation: e.target.value
            }
        })
    }

    onEstimateHoursChange(e){
        let estimate_hours = e.target.value;

        this.setState({
            project_data: {
                estimate_hours: estimate_hours,
                revenue: multiply(estimate_hours, this.state.project_data.hourly_rate),
                cost: multiply(estimate_hours,this.state.hourly_cost)
            }
        })

    }

    onHourlyCostChange(e){
        let hourly_cost = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            hourly_cost: hourly_cost,
            project_data: {
                cost: multiply(this.state.project_data.estimate_hours, hourly_cost)
            }
        })
    }

    onRevenueChange(e){

        let revenue = e.target.value;

        this.setState({
            project_data: {
                revenue: revenue,
                profit: difference(revenue,this.state.project_data.cost)
            }
        })
    }

    onCostChange(e){

        let cost = e.target.value;

        this.setState({
            project_data: {
                cost: cost,
                profit: difference(this.state.project_data.revenue,cost)
            }
        })
    }

    render(){

        let {projectName} = this.props;
        let data = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="member">
                <a className="member__short_info" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href={`#${data.id}`} aria-expanded="false" aria-controls={data.id}>
                    {data.full_name}
                </a>

                <div className="collapse member__member_full_info" id={data.id}>
                    <div className="member__full_info__row">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 com-lg-12 member__full_info__header">
                                {projectName}
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 member__full_info__column">
                                <label htmlFor="full_name" className="member__full_info__label">Member full name:</label>
                                <input id="full_name" type="text" name="full_name" value={data.full_name} onChange={this.onNameChange}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 member__full_info__column">
                                <label htmlFor="salary" className="member__full_info__label">Salary:</label>
                                <input id="salary" type="text" name="salary" value={data.salary} onChange={this.onSalaryChange}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 member__full_info__column">
                                <label className="member__full_info__label">Hourly cost: </label>
                                <input id="hourly_cost" type="text" name="hourly_cost" value={data.hourly_cost} onChange={this.onHourlyCostChange}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 member__full_info__column">
                                <label htmlFor="hourly_rate" className="member__full_info__label">Hourly rate</label>
                                <input id="hourly_rate" type="text" name="hourly_rate" value={data.project_data.hourly_rate} onChange={this.onHourlyRateChange}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 member__full_info__column">
                                <label htmlFor="occupation" className="member__full_info__label">Occupation in project (%): </label>
                                <input id="occupation" type="text" name="occupation" value={data.project_data.occupation} onChange={this.onOccupationChange}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 member__full_info__column">
                                <label htmlFor="estimate_hours" className="member__full_info__label">Estimate hours: </label>
                                <input id="estimate_hours" type="text" name="estimate_hours" value={data.project_data.estimate_hours} onChange={this.onEstimateHoursChange}/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 member__full_info__column">
                                <label className="member__full_info__label">Revenue: {data.project_data.revenue}</label>
                                {/*<input id="revenue" type="number" name="revenue" value={data.project_data.revenue} onChange={this.onRevenueChange}/>*/}
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 member__full_info__column">
                                <label className="member__full_info__label">Cost: {data.project_data.cost}</label>
                                {/*<input id="cost" type="number" name="cost" value={data.project_data.cost} onChange={this.onCostChange}/>*/}
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 member__full_info__column">
                                <label className="member__full_info__label">Profit: {data.project_data.profit}</label>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-sm-12 member__full_info__save">
                                <button className="modal-component positive-btn no-margin" onClick={this.save}>Save</button>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


        );
    }
}

export default Member;
```

For example: inside `onHourlyRateChange` function `estimate_hours` becomes `undefined` after change.

Inside `onEstimateHoursChange` state variables `this.state.project_data.hourly_rate` and `this.state.project_data.hourly_cost` becomes `undefined` too. I have no Idea why it happens. Maybe you can give me some advices?

Comment: If your `setState` requires reading previous state and your component is updated often, it is recommended to use the `setState(updaterFunction)` API to make sure you always get the latest state. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Make sure your event parameter is not undefined (and withing the boundaries of your app) before assigning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all your nested state is experiencing problems, i.e., nested inside project_data. Component is only updating child elements one time, i.e. on your first key press and for all subsequent key presses, it is not updating anything, instead values goes undefined for nested state items which is very strange. A work around for this can be like you can move all your nested state items as single level state items.
Ex:

```
this.state = {            
            project_data: { hourly_rate: 40 }
    }
```

instead you can move child item to parent

```
this.state = {            
            project_data_hourly_rate: 40
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought about that, but also thought that should be easiest way to update nested state, unfortunately not. So I will use your variant to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can partially update top-level properties of a state object, but nested updates won't work.

[immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper)'s `update` (replacement for [react-addons-update](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)) can be used to update nested properties:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const newData = update(myData, {
  x: {y: {z: {$set: 7}}},
  a: {b: {$push: [9]}}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it's good, but I think that I will choose another one as answer. The main reason why is because I don't want to add one more dependency

Comment: You're welcome. Use this technique then when your state becomes more complicated to the point when a simple flat structure is not enough.